# how to call a function within 32-bit C DLL within R

Tags: r, function, dll

After some trials and feedback received, I have the following R code, which I had hoped would provide me the use of functions from a 32-bit C DLL (swedll32.dll).

The swe_day_of_week function is as follows (swedll.h):

```
 /* monday = 0, ... sunday = 6 */
 DllImport int  CALL_CONV_IMP swe_day_of_week(double jd);
```

So my R code (32-bit R) is:

```
> dyn.load("C:/Users/VRHome/Documents/R/DLLs/swedll32.dll")
> Week <- as.integer(0) #so a 32-bit signed variable (aka Long in VBA)
> JD <- as.double(1234567.5)
> Week <- .C("_swe_day_of_week@8",JD)
```

I think the above R data types are correct and I checked that the _swe function indeed exists (getNativeSymbolInfo('_swe_day_of_week@8')). 
But R crashes (I think within this .C call). I must do something obviously wrong.

Any hints for me? Thanks.

All the best,

Victor

Comment: With `.C` you cannot have return values. Instead one uses output arguments. One solution would be to write a wrapper library, e.g. using Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks Ralf, indeed if I use a function from this DLL that have no result, the .C does not cause a crash... So I think that could be the case. Thanks. You say make them 'output arguments' but I thought R does not allow ByRef argument aka output argument (only through 'return(result)'). Of course I could make the 'result' a data frame (with all the output arguments) within a wrapper. My problem is that my C/dll/wrapper/compiling experience is zero. So it might be I need to educate myself. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Is this DLL from the Swiss Ephemeris code available here http://www.astro.com/ftp/swisseph/? In that case I would suggest building an R package using that source code instead of the DLL.

Comment: Indeed it is the DLL from the SE (Swiss Ephemeris) code. I had been thinking of that, but the amount of work to transcode is not that easy (certainly not if it changes...). But perhaps I can easily use the SE C-code within R (I assuem I need to check e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Calling-_002eCall and http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~bcaffo/statcomp/files/dotCall.pdf )?  I had hoped calling the DLL, would be the easiest, but I am starting to doubt that. Thanks Ralf for your continued feedback.

Answer (score 0):

[SODD](https://www.r-bloggers.com/sodd-stackoverflow-driven-development/) got the better of me. I have build a **very** rough package that compiles the Swiss Ephemeris code and creates an initial R package from it: https://github.com/rstub/SwissEphemeris

Right now the only available function is `day_of_week()`. Tested on Linux and Windows (via Appveyor).

Comment: Thanks Ralf for starting this!!! I started with a GirHub swephR, but my knowledge of R and C is far lower, so I would not know how to really begin. So this is great. Would it be possible to rename to swephR (as that is close the other names used in the Swiss Ephemeris environment)? And now some questions to show I don't know nothing! How do I use your code. I have downloaded your GitHub repository SwissEphemeris in my RStudio and see thus the files, but I assume I need to compile things? I have also Rtools on my Windows PC. Will send you a direct message

Comment: Can i reach you directly? I tried 'Install and build' on RStudio, but get error message: 
** libs
ar r libswe.a libswe/swedate.o libswe/swehouse.o libswe/swejpl.o libswe/swemmoon.o libswe/swemplan.o libswe/swepcalc.o libswe/sweph.o libswe/swepdate.o libswe/swephlib.o libswe/swecl.o libswe/swehel.o
make: ar: Command not found
make: *** [Makevars:11: libswe.a] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'SwissEphemeris'

Comment: @VictorReijs Please use the email address from DESCRIPTION. Right now it does not build on Windows.